# How to get count of distinct rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have used the following query:

```
select tblclass.classname,tblattendance.id 
 from tblclass,tblattendance
where tblclass.classcode=tblattendance.classcode 
  and tblattendance.attdate='2013-07-01'
```

Output of this query is as follows:

[image]

Now what I want is rather than the above result I want count of different classes like IB-2,IC-5.
Please tell me what modifications do I need to made in my query to get the desired result

Comment: thank you all.All the 3 answers worked for me:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) SQL clause and add the aggregate function [Count](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

```
select tblclass.classname, Count(tblattendance.id) as counter 
from tblclass,tblattendance 
where tblclass.classcode=tblattendance.classcode and tblattendance.attdate='2013-07-01'
group by tblclass.classname
```

Comment: i have a table tblstudent now i want a field where i can get no of students present in tblattendance on given date and total no of students in that class

Comment: Please open a new question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select count(tblattendance.id),tblclass.classname from tblclass,tblattendance 
where tblclass.classcode=tblattendance.classcode and tblattendance.attdate='2013-07-01' 
group by tblclass.classname
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT()` function for that with `GROUP BY`. Also use `JOIN`.

```
SELECT tc.classname, COUNT(tc.classname) AS COUNTS
  FROM tblclass tc 
  JOIN tblattendance tt
    ON tc.classcode = tt.classcode
 WHERE tt.attdate='2013-07-01'
 GROUP BY tc.classname
```